# Can OpenMetrics be directly integrated with Dynatrace?

Tags: database, integration, monitoring, dynatrace

I am using TigerGraph (a graph database), which exposes the metrics in OpenMetrics format. I want to use Dynatrace to monitor the metrics. Is there any direct integration between OpenMetrics and Dynatrace? How to integrate OpenMetrics with Dynatrace directly (without involving Prometheus)?